# CGIHTTPRequestHandler giving an error

Tags: python, cgihttpserver

`CGIHTTPRequestHandler` gives an import error saying no such module available.

```
import CGIHTTPServer

import BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):

    cgi_directories = ["/cgi"]

PORT = 8000

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT

httpd.serve_forever()
```

I get the following response.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PYTHON/cgiserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler
  File "D:/PYTHON\CGIHTTPServer.py", line 9, in <module>
    handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CGIHTTPRequestHandler'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `CGIHTTPServer.py`. (And don't forget to remove `CGIHTTPServer.pyc`.)

Otherwise it conflicts with the standard module [`CGIHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html); prevents you to import the module.